# Как найти элемент на странице с определенным атрибутом зная только атрибут?

Tags: javascript

Дамы и господа, допустим есть некий элемент на странице и он нам не известен... Это может быть `div`, `span` или `p` и так далее... Как можно найти этот элемент зная только его `Attribute`. Метод который я ниже привел не дал ни каких результатов... Получаю `null`.  Единственный вариант которым я чего-то добился это общепринятый и всеми известны, это `variant_3`, который меня не интересует...

```js
var bodyChildren = document.body.children;
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (var i = 0; i < bodyChildren.length; i++) {
  var variant_0 = bodyChildren[i].getAttribute('scrollWrap');
  var variant_1 = bodyChildren[i].getAttribute('id');
}

var variant_2 = wrapper.getAttribute('scrollWrap');

var variant_3 = wrapper.getAttribute('id');

console.log('variant_0 ' + variant_0);
console.log('variant_1 ' + variant_1);
console.log('variant_2 ' + variant_2);
console.log('variant_3 ' + variant_3);
variant_3.className = 'variant_3';

console.log(wrapper);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" scrollWrap></div>
```

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) / [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: @Deonis тоже null

Comment: Благодарю всех за участия

Comment: Покажите HTML-код элемента, к которому пытаетесь обратиться

Comment: @Deonis, он в примере...

Comment: Не заметил, да и не важно уже, т.к. вижу, что разобрались.

Comment: Да благодарю...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Находит первый элемент с заданным атрибутом.

```js
var ell = document.querySelector("*[scrollWrap]");
console.log(ell);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">hi man</div>
<div id="wrapper2" scrollWrap>hallow</div>
<div id="wrapper3">hi</div>
```

Находит все элементы с заданным атрибутом

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*[scrollWrap]");
for (var el of elements) {
  console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">hi man</div>
<div id="wrapper2" scrollWrap>hallow 1</div>
<div id="wrapper3">hi</div>
<div id="wrapper4" scrollWrap>hallow 2</div>
```

Comment: Вот черт)))))  Прикинь, ну вот ни на секунду не вспомнил о `querySelectorAll`...  Благодарю...

Comment: @Air Пожалуйста. Я и не заметил что это ты спрашивал, тебя давно на сайте знаю ))

Answer (score 1):

```js
var e = document.querySelectorAll('*[scrollWrap]');

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  console.log(e[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1" scrollWrap></div>
<div id="wrapper2"></div>
<div id="wrapper3" scrollWrap></div>
<div id="wrapper4" title></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю всех за участия

Answer (score 1):

Варианты 0 и 1 дают null, потому, что Вы в цикле пробегаете по всем элементам, а нужно прерывать цикл, когда нашли нужный элемент

Вариант 2 работает вполне адекватно. Он возвращает значение атрибута в виде пустой строки `""`, что логично. Запись

```
<div id="wrapper" scrollWrap></div>
```

эквивалентна

```
<div id="wrapper" scrollWrap=""></div>
```

А вообще, как советуют в соседних ответах, для этой задачи нужно использовать `querySelector / querySelectorAll`

Comment: Благодарю всех за участия